# How to make a h:graphicImage a link to Google?

Tags: html, jsf, hyperlink

How can I make h:graphicImage a link to http://www.google.com?

```
<h:graphicImage value="/imagenes/Powertrain_GM.gif" width="50" />
```

I tried to put it like this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <h:graphicImage value="/imagenes/Powertrain_GM.gif" width="50" />
</a>
```

But does not work...

Also tried:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">
    <img src="/imagenes/Powertrain_GM.gif">
</a>
```

But nothing... Everything is inside `<h:form>...</h:form>`

Help please.

Comment: Your code worked for me. Do you have any other links on the page that work?

Comment: @JosefE. I have no idea why it works know. I used the second code. Any ideas of this strange problem? I did not changed anything and know works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why it works know. I used the second code. Any ideas of this strange problem? I did not changed anything and know works...